# IRC (RFC 1459) message prefix

Tags: irc, rfc

This question seems fairly pedantic, however it feels reasonably important when trying to follow the RFC. I am trying to write an IRC client and I am using the RFC  to follow how the protocol should be written. I came across the section for message prefixes and was slightly confused by what was written.

> Each IRC message may consist of up to three main parts: the prefix
>      (optional), the command, and the command parameters (of which there
>      may be up to 15).  The prefix, command, and all parameters are
>      separated by one (or more) ASCII space character(s) (0x20).
>
> The presence of a prefix is indicated with a single leading ASCII
>      colon character (':', 0x3b), which must be the first character of the
>      message itself.  There must be no gap (whitespace) between the colon
>      and the prefix.

My question concerns the first sentence in the second paragraph; `ASCII colon character (':', 0x3b)`. With (to my understanding) `0x3b`being the ASCII character for a semi-colon, **does this mean that the prefix may be either semi-colon or a colon, or is it simply a typo in the document?** I'm going ahead with using a colon for now, however my curiosity is nagging away at me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colon `:` (0x3a) is correct.

This is [the first errata listed for RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=1459).